# Flutter: How do I create a line of text where one String goes to the end of the line while the other stays at the beginning?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, format

I'm working on a flutter app, where I have some text in a Text widget. The text has two components, one word, and one number. I want to format it such that the word appears at the beginning of the line, but the number goes to the end of the line. For instance, assuming the box below spans the whole screen:

`Word 1                         Num`

I want this to be dynamic, so that no matter what your screen size, the word and the number go to opposite ends of the line. The only solution I could find was using padRight, but I'm not sure how to make it dynamic since the I'm not sure how to set the width parameter. Is there a way for me to map the screen width to the number of characters in a line? Or any other tool I'm missing?

My current solution is something like this:

```
Text(
" " + name + ":".padRight(32) + number,
)
```

This clearly doesn't work because I chose 32 arbitrarily and it won't dynamically change.

Appreciate any help, thanks!!

Comment: Wouldn't Row help here? Like `Row(children: [Text("name"), Spacer(), Text("number")])`

Comment: The other solution that comes to my mind is that you can pass MediaQuery values to your padRight to make it dynamic, like `padRight((MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1).toInt())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
      children: [
           Text("Word 1"),
           Text("Num"),
      ]
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code, you use [`Spacer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) class

**Using Spacer**

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text("Word 1"),
        Spacer(),
        Text("Name"),
      ],
    ),
```

**Using MainAxisAlignment:**

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Text("Word 1"),
    Text("Name"),
  ],
),
```

Refer Layout [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

**Try like this **

```
Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
     color: Colors.black26,
   ),
    child: const ListTile(
      title: Text("Word 1"),
      trailing: Text("Num"),
    ),
  )
```

it will work perfectly all devices